# Invalid object name 'dbo.PolyinstantiationExample'

Tags: sql-server

I am using VM Ware with SQL Server Management Studio and I have created the PolyinstantiationExample table already but continue to have errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwg0s.png)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score -2):

I have tried using another table name.

```
Use ContosoUniversity2
Go

create table dbo.tblA(
    pKey integer Not Null identity (1,1),
    EmployeeID integer not Null,
    CEmployeeID varchar(1) Not Null,
    DepartmentID integer Not Null,
    CDepartmentID varchar(1) Not Null,
    Salary money Not Null,
    CSalary varchar(1) Not Null,
    CRecord varchar(1) Not Null,
    Constraint PK_tblA Primary Key Clustered (pKey ASC),
    Constraint UK_tblA_Employee_EmployeeID UNIQUE (EmployeeID,CEmployeeID)
)
go

SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.tblA values (1, 'T', 100, 'T', 234567.89, 'A', 'A');
```

But it works, I don't what the server variables setting are.
Probably some administrator just accidentally update the environment recklessly while you create the table